# Extract month and day from a field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do you select Month and day like in 'MMDD' format from a column, which has dates in '2014-01-12'(Datetime) format?

Comment: The first mistake was storing a date as a character data type instead of using the native date/datetime type. After that, nothing good can happen.

Comment: Please give us more info. Is your field a datetime field?

Comment: Try `SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(DateColumn AS DATE), 1), '/', '')`

Comment: Srry, Ive changed to datetime

Comment: If it was Date data type your values would look something like `2014-11-01` not `'11/01/2014`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filed is a Date or DateTime, I would use the function [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

For example, this gets the current year:

```
DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

View the msdn page for the full documentation.

If your field is text, use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert your field to a DATE, then use the first method with the converted date as your value.

For example:

```
DATEPART(year, CONVERT(DATE, '11/1/2014'))
```

Complete Copy/Paste Example

```
DECLARE @DateVal VARCHAR(10) = '11/01/2014'
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, @DateVal)) AS VARCHAR),
        @Day VARCHAR(2) = CAST(DATEPART(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, @DateVal)) AS VARCHAR)
PRINT REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(@Month)) + @Month + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(@Day)) + @Day
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't finish my answer. I'll post complete code in a moment.